# Update middleware in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware

Is there any way to MODIFY (*NOT* replace) a middleware in rails?

So instead of:

```
config.middleware.delete ::Rack::Cache
config.middleware.use ::Rack::Cache, :metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false
```

I want to simply write something like `config.middleware.find!(::Rack::Cache).verbose = false`.

**UPDATE:** The reason to do it is because the capybara-webkit [prints tons of messages](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/234#issuecomment-3375900) when running from cucumber.

Comment: Are you trying to simply turn the :verbose flag to false? Or are you trying to have it be verbose for some calls and not-verbose for others?

Comment: Just set the flag to false. Don't want to remove/inser Rask to avoid messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
  # Disable annoying Cache messages:
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {:metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false}
```

This worked for my particular case (Rails cache was used by [Dragonfly and wasn't inserted anymore](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/issues/159)).

I don't think there is a way of doing what I originally asked though.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this particular middleware, you can set the Rack environment option to be merged with its default configuration as per: http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/configuration

Comment: This is just poor `Rack::Cache` config, not inside Rails. But even overriding env from Rails before_filter doesn't work. So still no luck.

Comment: NOTE: There's a special config in rails `config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {:metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false}` that IS SUPPOSED TO WORK, but it doesn't.