# Too verbose log entries with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haproxy

**UPDATE**: It was not the problem that HAProxy doesn't recognize Rails, it was my mistake. The real problem though is that every request clogs up the log. Updated the entire question.

Every time the rails process receive a request, it generates a line like this in the rails.xxxx.log:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

How do I silence them?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question and the solution here:

[Update middleware in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796055/update-middleware-in-rails)

I also ended up with:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {:metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false}
```

Honestly I think it shouldn't be this hard to find the solution, as it can easily mess up logs with medium traffic.